# Android Keystore: how to determine which encryption was use to create it?

Tags: java, android, keytool

Here's the scenario:  I created and released an android app a year ago.  I was using Java 5 to create the keystore and alias.  Now when I try to sign my app with the instructions found here: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html I get this:

`keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect`

I'm positive that the keystore isn't busted because it's binary file is untouched from the one I committed to a private git repo when releasing the original app.  The password is unchanged and has been maintained via passpack.

What has changed:  my os and java version.  I was originally running OS X 10.5 and Java 5.0 and now using OS X 10.6.8 and Java 6.

I think I've whittled it down to a mismatch in the encryption.  Anyone know what the default encryption for that setup would have been?

Also, I likely built the keystore with Eclipse ADT 20.x for eclipse ganymede/helios.  Can't find any default information regarding that either.

Answer (score 0):

Although the app signing instructions tell you to use RSA with a keysize of 2048, the original defaults from Java 5 aren't identical.

Here's the combination that finally unlocked the keystore created with Java 5.0:

`keytool -list -v -keystore sumall_android_keystore -keyalg DSA -keysize 1024 -sigalg SHA1withDSA`

Java 5.0's keytool uses DSA 1024 to create keys by default.
Java 6 and 7 have both changed the default encryption.

see: Supported Algorithms and Key Sizes in  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/keytool.html